# Display only the top records according to there stage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where table has 
Record_id,Record_Stage,Other_Column

```
1,A,Text1
1,B,Text2
1,C,Text3
1,D,Text4
2,A,SText1
2,B,SText2
```

My output should be based on record_id

1)the record with stage D for record_id 1

2)record_id 2 with Stage B is displayed as there are no Stage C and Stage D

O/p

```
1,D,Text4
2,B,SText2
```

I am manipulating this case in a SQL Server view,It would be great help If someone can help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy with `row_number()`

```
select *
from   (
           select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Record_id 
                                                 order by Record_Stage desc)
           from   yourtable
       ) d
where  d.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    ID INT,
    Stage VARCHAR(10),
    Other VARCHAR(45)
    );

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'A', 'Text1'),
(1, 'B', 'Text2'),
(1, 'C', 'Text3'),
(1, 'D', 'Text4'),
(2, 'A', 'SText1'),
(2, 'B', 'SText2');

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT MAX(T.ID) AS ID,
       MAX(T.Stage) AS Stage
FROM T 
GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT T.*
FROM T INNER JOIN CTE ON T.ID = CTE.ID AND T.Stage = CTE.Stage;
```

Results:

```
+----+----+-------+--------+
|    | ID | Stage | Other  |
+----+----+-------+--------+
|  1 |  1 | D     | Text4  |
|  2 |  2 | B     | SText2 |
+----+----+-------+--------+
```